# How to convert iOS date string into formatd date using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hey using **ionic + cordova**, when I fetch the selected contact with birthdate, date values comes into this formate (1424779200000). I know its correct value, but now I want to convert this value into date and display into my application. I don't want to write any native code for everyone (like ios, android...). Is there any javascript for this....?

Comment: `new Date(1424779200000)`

Answer (score 0):

use moment.js (http://momentjs.com/)
e.g.

```
moment(yourVal).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // February 24th 2015, 11:54:41 am
```